# (Here Android Sdk) How can one obtain the Place instance on clicking a POI on map?

Tags: android, here-api

On clicking a map object I get the ViewObject list instance which after a few typecasts becomes MapCartoMarker.
From MapCartoMarker instance I am able to get placename. I don't know how to proceed further in order to obtain Place instance.

Answer (score 1):

From [MapCartoMarker](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-mapcartomarker.html), get the [Location](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-location.html#topic-apiref), then [LocationInfo](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-locationinfo.html#topic-apiref). Please check the FOREIGN_ID and the other [attributes](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-locationinfo-field.html#topic-apiref) listed there.